# How do I turn off automatic workspace building in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, workspace

I'm using Eclipse Juno on Mac 10.7.5 (Java 6).  I have several Maven projects imported into my workspace and despite the 10 GB of memory on my machine, my Eclipse session sometimes grinds to a halt while its "Building workspace."  How do I turn off automatic workspace building?  I'll do it on my own if necessary, but for now, its completely slowing down my amazing programming groove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows its untick "Project -> Build Automatically" if I understand you correctly. probably the same on Mac.

Comment: I confirm it is the same on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

`Project` -> `Build Automatically` Check that it deactivates the tick next to the line of the menu.